# How to check if ode system is gradient system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I check for a given (nonlinear) system of ODEs if this is a gradient system? Meaning how do I check the existence of a pseudo Riemann metric and a potential function? May be somebody could post a simple example or give a literature hint?

Thanks ahead!!

Comment: What do you mean by gradient system?

Comment: In the easiest case: http://planetmath.org/GradientSystem.html more general: http://books.google.de/books?id=mJYw3u2HniUC&lpg=PA10&dq=gradient%20system%20potential%20riemann%20metric&hl=de&pg=PA10#v=onepage&q=gradient%20system%20potential%20riemann%20metric&f=false

Comment: $F=(F_1,\ldots,F_n) \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ has a potnetial means that there is a function $V \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ such that $F(x)=\nabla V(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is simply connected, there exists such a $V$ iff
$\partial_iF_j=\partial_jF_i$ for every $i<j$. As an example, take $F(x,y)=(y,x)$. Clearly $\partial_1F_2=\partial_2F_1$, therefore $F$ has a potential. In fact $V(x,y)=xy$ is a potnetial.If you replace $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus 0$ it's a different story though!

Comment: with \delta_i F_j being the derivative with respect to the i-th variable of the partial derivative with respect to the j-th ?

Comment: $\partial_iF_j=\partial F_j/\partial x_i$